# Value not changing when radio button is pressed - AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

What i'm trying to do is when a product is selected the different types of that product are brought in the browser.
Here's what I got:

**script.js**

```
function showCtrl($scope,  $http) {
$scope.products = [
 {
    "category":"Pens",
    "label":"p1",
    "images":"d-u-b/pens.png"
},
{
    "category":"Cozies",
    "label":"p2",
    "images":"d-u-b/cozie.png"
}
];
$scope.prod = {"name": "Cozies"};
$scope.typSelect = 'plain';
$http.get("products/"+$scope.prod.name+".json").success(function(data){
    $scope.type = data;

});
}
```

**customo.php(code snippet where its being called)**

```
<div class="pro" ng-repeat="product in products">
 <label for="{{product.label}}" class="p">
  <input id="{{product.label}}" type="radio" ng-model="prod.name" name="name" value="{{product.category}}"/>
  <h3>{{product.category}}</h3><img ng-src="{{product.images}}" alt="{{product.category}}"/>
 </label>
</div>
```

My problem is that prod.name is not changing in the js and not calling the correct json file. I displayed prod.name in the html and it changes correctly when I click the radio button but the types will not change according to the product I selected.

Can anyone see what i'm doing wrong and how to fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thats because your javascript code is not paying attention to changes of that variable. To make your controller observe `prod.name` you need to use [$watch](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/%24rootScope.Scope#%24watch) method of `$scope` variable.

```
$scope.$watch('prod.name', function () {
  $http.get("products/"+$scope.prod.name+".json").success(function(data){
    $scope.type = data;
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure but I think your $http code is incorrect. I've changed your code slightly. Let me know if it does what you're expecting. Basically, I've added an ng-click directive on the radio button html. When clicked, it calls a function getData on the scope that passes in the product. From there, I extract the category and display that in the console. You can use that to get the file name and get the data from the json file.

script.js:

```
angular.module('app', [])
.controller('showCtrl', showCtrl);


function showCtrl($scope,  $http) {
$scope.products = [
 {
    "category":"Pens",
    "label":"p1",
    "images":"d-u-b/pens.png"
  },
  {
      "category":"Cozies",
      "label":"p2",
      "images":"d-u-b/cozie.png"
  }
  ];
//$scope.prod = {"name": "Cozies"};
$scope.typSelect = 'plain';
$scope.getData = function(prod) {
  // $http.get($scope.prod.name + ".json").success(function(data){
  //   $scope.type = data;
    console.log('getting data from ' + prod.category);
};
}
```

index.html:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en" ng-app="app">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body ng-controller="showCtrl">
    <script src= "angular.js"></script>

    <script src= "script.js"></script>

    <div class="pro" ng-repeat="product in products">
     <label for="{{product.label}}" class="p">
      <input id="{{product.label}}" type="radio" ng-model="prod.name" name="name" value="{{product.category}}" ng-click="getData(product)"/>
      <h3>{{product.category}}</h3>
      <!-- <img ng-src="{{product.images}}" alt="{{product.category}}"/> -->

     </label>
</div>

{{prod.name}}
</body>
</html>
```